# How do store the data i have input and detected it's data type in Java?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am making a program that detects the input data type t whether it's integer or double . I have don't the following code so far. But I don't know how to store the data I input.

**Code:**

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HeightCalc {
    public static int temp,result;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        if (input.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("Integer.");
        }

        else if (input.hasNextFloat() || input.hasNextDouble()) {
            System.out.println("Double.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the apache commons lib you can use StringUtils and NumberUtils.
In general define a variable for the scanner input and validate its content, validating the input directly is more restrictive.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.math;

public class HeightCalc {
    public static int temp,result;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        String input = scanner.nextLine();

  if (StringUtils.isNumeric(input))
  {
     System.out.println("Integer.");
  }

  else if (NumberUtils.isCreatable(input))
  {
      System.out.println("Double.");
  }

 System.out.println("Input:" + input);
}
}
```

You can store the input in a variable like in the above example.

```
String myInput = scanner.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

if I get it right you need to store input number value to one variable?

I would create `Number inputValue` variable and into it I would store values from scanner.

```
        Number inputValue;

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        if (input.hasNextInt())
        {
            inputValue = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("int.");
        }  else if (input.hasNextFloat() || input.hasNextDouble())
        {
            inputValue = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Double.");
        }
```

inputValue will inherit class from `.nextInt()` or `nextDouble()`.

However I would consider storing input to one variable to get rid of this condition and derivate other number classes from it.

Example for int

```
inputValue = input.nextDouble();

public int getIntValue(){
   return inputValue.intValue();
}
```